# Cracked Cleanout Cover - What to replace it with?

Tags: plumbing

The rusty cast iron drain cleanout in my basement is cracked and I can't seem to find a matching piece at Lowes/Home Depot. The cover is about 5" wide. What would be the best thing I can use to seal this off?

[image: Cracked Drain Cleanout]

Comment: A builders merchant?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a shopping question. OP has done due diligence and found that something will probably need to be retrofit. I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd use a 1/4" aluminum or 1/8" galvanized steel plate with a layer of rubber or neoprene underneath. This way it's easily reusable.

Just drill holes for the studs and use new galvanized nuts and suitable washers.

Answer (score 0):

Get an Abs or PVC (better) Cap of a pipe bigger than your 5 inches to drill two holes through and use high-quality silicone to create a seal on the old metal. Clean the old metal surface with a wire brush (Dremel). Get new washers and nuts and you are in business.